# How can I dynamically updatea StaticText label after a button click event in wxPerl?

Tags: perl, dynamic, wxperl

I have a Static Text displaying the currently selected file name. I'd like it to update every time the user chooses a new file using the 'Select File' button.

I've tried using the Update() method inside the EVT_BUTTON subroutine call but is not working.

Below is a section of my code.
Please excuse any bad coding practices, relatively new to this.

```
      $self->{class_source_txt} = Wx::StaticText->new(
                                 $panel,
                                              1,
               "Classifier Source: $classifier",
                         [-1,-1]);

      $self->{file_select} = Wx::Button->new(
                $panel,
                1,
                "Select Classifier",
               );

      EVT_BUTTON(   
        $self,
        1,
        sub{
        $classifier = FileSelect();
        $self->{class_source_txt}->Update();
            }
                );
```

Specifically what I am trying to do is to have the `Classifier Source: $classifier` line display the new value of `$classifier` created by the `EVT_BUTTON`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$self->{class_source_txt}->SetLabel($classifier);
```

You could install [Wx::Demo](http://search.cpan.org/~mdootson/Wx-Demo-0.21/) and learn from these examples.